# Unable to find array element using $ operator in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in mongoDB that looks like this

> { "_id" : ObjectId("55edbc999113b823360aa912"), "car" : "Honda",
>   "color" : [ "Black", "White" ] }

I'm trying to update the color Black to Grey in array field "color" using this query

```
db.words.update({_id:'55edbc999113b823360aa912', color:Black},{$set:{'color.$' : 'Grey' } } )
```

But I get this error.

> 2015-09-07T12:38:14.259-0400 ReferenceError: Black is not defined

If I try to use commas around the Black, still nothing is found

```
db.words.update({_id:'55edbc999113b823360aa912', color:'Black'},{$set:{'color.$' : 'Grey' } } )
```

> WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

What's wrong in the update query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten to specify the `_id` field is an ObjectId, not a string:

```
db.words.update(
    { _id: ObjectId('55edbc999113b823360aa912'), color: 'Black' },
    { $set: { 'color.$' : 'Grey' } }
)
```

You do need the quotes around 'Black' so the second query is closer, just missing the `ObjectId()`.

Comment: I still get the same result - WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

Comment: It's working now. I was writing to wrong document. Thanks!